# Struggling to separate breadth first search section of my main loop into its own function

Tags: python, function, class, breadth-first-search, path-finding

I am trying to make a breadth first search pathfinding tool and this is where I have got to so far:

```
from collections import deque
import pygame as pg
import sys

# Set the size of the window
width, height = 960, 640
size = (width, height)
GREEN = (0, 200, 0)
RED = (200, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (205, 165, 0)
pg.init()

# Create the game window
win = pg.display.set_mode(size)
pg.display.set_caption('Breadth First Search')
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# Set the number of columns and rows for the grid
cols, rows = int((3 * width / 80)), 32

# Calculate the width and height of each square in the grid
w = int(width * (3 / 4)) // cols
h = height // rows

# Initialize empty lists for the grid, queue, visited squares, and path
grid = []
queue, visited = deque(), []
path = []


# Define a class called Square to represent each square in the grid
class Square:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.x = i
        self.y = j
        self.neighbors = []
        self.prev = None
        self.wall = False
        self.visited = False
        self.start = False
        self.end = False

    # Function to draw the square on the window
    def show(self, win, col):
        if self.wall:
            col = (255, 255, 255)
        elif self.start:
            col = (0, 255, 0)  # Green for start node
        elif self.end:
            col = (255, 0, 0)  # Red for end node
        pg.draw.rect(win, col, (self.x * w, self.y * h, w - 1, h - 1))

    # Function to add neighboring squares to the current square
    def add_neighbors(self, grid):
        deltas = [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)]
        for dx, dy in deltas:
            new_x, new_y = self.x + dx, self.y + dy
            if 0 <= new_x < cols and 0 <= new_y < rows:
                self.neighbors.append(grid[new_x][new_y])


class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, text, font_size, colour, id):
        self.rect = pg.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.text = text
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.font = pg.font.Font(None, font_size)
        self.colour = colour
        self.update_hover()
        self.is_hovered = False
        self.id = id

    def update_hover(self):
        self.hover_colour = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i + j, self.colour, (50, 50, 50)))

    def draw(self, surface):
        self.update_hover()
        current_colour = self.hover_colour if self.is_hovered else self.colour
        pg.draw.rect(surface, current_colour, self.rect)

        text_surface = self.font.render(self.text, True, (0, 0, 0))
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        surface.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    def check_hover(self, mouse_pos):
        self.is_hovered = self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)

    def check_click(self, mouse_pos):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)


# Function to handle mouse clicks and update wall states
def click_wall(pos, state):
    i = pos[0] // w
    j = pos[1] // h
    if pos[0] <= width * 0.75:
        grid[i][j].wall = state


# Function to place start or end node on click
def place_node(pos, is_start, is_end):
    i = pos[0] // w
    j = pos[1] // h

    # Clear existing start or end nodes
    for row in grid:
        for square in row:
            if is_start:
                square.start = False
            else:
                square.end = False

    # Set the new start or end node
    if is_start:
        grid[i][j].start = True
        start_node = grid[i][j]
        return i, j

    elif is_end:
        grid[i][j].end = True
        end_node = grid[i][j]
        return i, j


def reset():
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(rows):
            grid[i][j].wall = False
            grid[i][j].visited = False
            grid[i][j].prev = None
            grid[i][j].start = False
            grid[i][j].end = False

    # Clear the queue, visited list, and path list
    queue.clear()
    visited.clear()
    path.clear()


# Create the grid of squares
for i in range(cols):
    arr = [Square(i, j) for j in range(rows)]
    grid.append(arr)

# Add neighbors to each square
for i in range(cols):
    for j in range(rows):
        grid[i][j].add_neighbors(grid)

# Set the initial start and end points
button_col = (150, 150, 150)

buttons = [
    Button((0.75 * width) + (width * 0.025), height * 0.08, width / 5, height / 15, 'START', 40, button_col, 'start'),
    Button((0.75 * width) + (width * 0.025), height * 0.08 + height / 15 + 10, width / 5, height / 15, 'BFS', 40,
           (200, 0, 0), 'alg')
]

# Main loop for the game
def main():
    completed = False
    noflag = True
    start = False
    algorithm = 1
    colours = {1: RED, 2: ORANGE, 3: GREEN}
    alg_name = {1: 'BFS', 2: 'DFS', 3: 'A STAR'}
    start_node = None
    end_node = None

    # Event handling loop
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if buttons[0].check_click(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                    start = True
                if buttons[1].check_click(pg.mouse.get_pos()):
                    if algorithm != 3:
                        algorithm += 1
                    else:
                        algorithm = 1
                    buttons[1].colour = colours[algorithm]
                    buttons[1].text = alg_name[algorithm]
                    print(algorithm)
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                    click_wall(pg.mouse.get_pos(), True)
                if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[2]:
                    click_wall(pg.mouse.get_pos(), False)
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                for button in buttons:
                    button.check_hover(pg.mouse.get_pos())
                if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                    click_wall(pg.mouse.get_pos(), True)
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    if start_node and end_node:
                        start = True
                if event.key == pg.K_c:
                    reset()
                    start = False
                    start_node = None
                    end_node = None
                    completed = False
                # Check for 's' key press to place the start node
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    start_node = grid[place_node(pg.mouse.get_pos(), True, False)[0]][place_node(pg.mouse.get_pos(), True, False)[1]]

                # Check for 'e' key press to place the end node
                if event.key == pg.K_e:
                    end_node = grid[place_node(pg.mouse.get_pos(), False, True)[0]], [place_node(pg.mouse.get_pos(), False, True)[1]]

        # Check if the start flag is set
        if start:
            queue.append(start_node)
            start_node.visited = True
            # Check if the queue is not empty
            if len(queue) > 0:
                current = queue.popleft()
                # Check if the current square is the end point
                if current.end:
                    temp = current
                    while temp.prev:
                        path.append(temp.prev)
                        temp = temp.prev
                    if not completed:
                        completed = True
                        print("Done")
                    elif completed:
                        continue
                # If not at the end, add neighbors to the queue
                if not completed:
                    for i in current.neighbors:
                        if not i.visited and not i.wall:
                            i.visited = True
                            i.prev = current
                            queue.append(i)
            else:
                if noflag and not completed:
                    print("Not completed")
                    font = pg.font.Font(None, 36)
                    text = font.render('No Solution', True, (255, 255, 255))
                    text_rect = (width-100, height-100)
                    win.blit(text, text_rect)
                    noflag = False
                else:
                    continue

        # Update the window with the current state of the grid
        win.fill((200, 200, 200))
        for i in range(cols):
            for j in range(rows):
                square = grid[i][j]
                square.show(win, (0, 0, 0))
                if square in path:
                    square.show(win, (0, 95, 115))
                elif square.visited:
                    square.show(win, (202, 103, 2))
                if square in queue:
                    square.show(win, (174, 32, 18))


        pg.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (width * 0.75, 0, width * 0.25, height))
        for button in buttons:
            button.draw(win)

        pg.display.flip()


# Run the main loop
main()
```

However, I would also like to add other pathfinding algorithms in the future.
To be able to do this I need to separate the bfs (the bit after # Check if the start flag is set) from the main loop I think.

Any idea on how to do this?

I have tried taking the existing code and putting it in a function, passing in values but can't seem to get it to work.